# Is there a way around the Awesomium 1.7 WebCore Shutdown Bug

Tags: c#, browser, awesomium

I am developing a webbrowser with Awesomium and I am using the newest version of it. However it has some issues when I dispose WebControls and when I shutdown the WebCore ( which also disposes the WebControls ).

Does anyone know a way around this? Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you doing exactly? why shutdown (on exit or before) - and some details, code/test.

Comment: Perhaps the WebControl(s) you disposed were still "owned" by Awesomium and it couldn't handle with such a case?

Comment: Well no I did some research and it is a known bug in Awesomium 1.7 Release Candidate. But I am wondering if there is a way around it

Answer (score 1):

I have done a little bit of testing with this. I was trying to use the WPF version of WebControl and found that it can leak quite badly, especially when you are creating and destroying a lot of WebControls over time. So, I was fooling around with WindowsFormsHost and using the WinForms version of WebControl and even though it doesn't leak, I too was having the same issue you describe. It turns out you want to explicitly call Dispose AFTER the handle's to your window are cleaned up.

In WPF, I inherited WindowsFormsHost and specified an override to DestroyWindowCore like so:

```
    protected override void DestroyWindowCore(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hwnd) {
        base.DestroyWindowCore(hwnd);// clean up handles

        // Disposing here prevents access violation from crashing non-debug instances
        // Confirmed to prevent access violation on WebCore shutdown as well

        webControl1.Dispose();
        webControl1 = null;
    }

    // This code seems to work in WinForms, I placed this in Form1.cs:
    protected override void DestroyHandle() {

        base.DestroyHandle();
        webControl1.Dispose();
    }
```

I would recommend playing around with different placements of where you dispose of the control. Typically after the host has released it's handles. I can confirm that I no longer have this issue and the Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl is functioning properly on Dispose

Edit, I have uploaded my test project to DropBox [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/72849414/AwesomiumTest.zip) . The solution is for Visual Studio 2012 and targeting .net 4.5. Hope this helps!

Comment: I already solved it differently, but thanks for the resonse ;)

Comment: Maybe you can update your question to include what you found?

Comment: Okay, I will answer my own question

Comment: @SilverX Your test project isn't working for me.  It compiles and runs, but the spawned browser shows no content (just grey screen).

Comment: I am sorry, seems to work fine for me. If it compiles than you must be using 1.7 atleast. Do you have any more information? Gray screen usually means that the control is loaded but it did not navigate to any page.. perhaps check to ensure it's navigating somewhere?

Comment: Yes, sorry I apologize, the test project doesn't navigate to anything. Source="h t t p://youtube.com"  in SpawnWindow.xaml should do the trick. I will update the dropbox file thank you.

Comment: Thanks.  However, the file I downloaded does have: `WebBrowser.Source = new Uri("http://youtube.com/");` in the SpawnWindow constructor.  I'll download your update and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @SilverX Ok, I've researched further and the Webbrowser control is crashing, as tracing the code shows that the OnCrashed event is occurring, but there is no useful info about why it crashed from what I can tell.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this issue myself. I have only briefly tested the Awesomium library. I feel it still has some maturing to do. One thing to note however is I do NOT have chrome installed. If it's anything like IE it will attempt to use the system installed version first, then fallback to the redistributed control if it doesn't exist. This is useful for many reasons, however might be the source of the crash. Sorry I can't help out further, if I find anything I will update.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding some code to the FormClosing event in my main form:

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  foreach(WebControl awWebControl in WebCore.Views)
  {
     //Dispose all active views in WebCore
     awWebControl.Dispose();

  }
  //then you can Shutdown the WebCore
  WebCore.Shutdown();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is great if you only have a couple of instances alive for the entire span of your application. But if you are like myself and constantly creating and destroying browser instances, waiting until the app is shutting down means there could be hundreds of MB of memory trapped in your application. For me, it makes more sense to dispose of the control when the element hosting it gets destroyed.

Comment: @SilverX yes, maybe, but when I dispose a webcontrol while it is running the underlying webview doesnt get disposed. So when I tried to shutdown the core and stop the websession it crashes because those underlying views were still there. With this code it seems to be disposing the underlying views as wel
NOTE : I do dispose the webcontrol while the application is running when a tab is removed.

Comment: That's very odd considering I cannot reproduce what you describe when I dispose it using the guidelines I mentioned. I also have no need to manually dispose the views when the app shuts down. I have tested in both WinForms and WPF. The WPF app being more demanding and recreating views, not just when tabs are removed, but every time the tabcontrol goes in / out of view as well. It might be worth trying, if the views aren't being removed properly there's a good chance it isn't disposing properly either when you dispose the webcontrol, so the view is stuck until you dispose it manually

Comment: @SilverX I have now tested it with wpf so I rewrote all my code and now I haven't got this issue anymore. The only problem is that the wpf webcontrol has some other issues. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: Yes, I too am using WPF but hosting the WinForms WebControl because of the GPU accelerated graphics and better memory consumption. And no problem, I remember reading this post when I was having the issue so I thought I would share how I solved it.